# angular $http / jquery complete equivalent

Tags: angularjs, http, callback, promise, angular-promise

Is there a way to emulate jquery 'complete' callback with angular $http module? I have some code I would like to execute no matter whether the request succeeded or failed and at the moment I find myself having to write this:

```
$http.get(someUrl).success(function(){
        successCode();
        completeCode();
    }).error(function(){
        errorCode();
        completeCode();
    })
```

but I would rather write something like:

```
$http.get(someUrl).success(function(){
        successCode();
    }).error(function(){
        errorCode();
    }).complete(function(){
        completeCode();
    })
```

I've tried also using the promise API but I end up having the same problem. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update Aug 2014:** `.always` has been renamed `.finally` in recent versions of Angular. Prefer `.finally` to `.always`.

Note that in order to support IE8 you have to call it with bracket notation as `["finally"]`.

---

You can use `.always` in AngularJS

This change is **rather new** (you could do that in jQuery for a while), you can see the commit [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6605adf). This requires you to have AngularJS  1.1.5 or higher.

> `always(callback)` – allows you to observe either the fulfillment or rejection of a promise,
>      but to do so without modifying the final value. This is useful to release resources or do some
>      clean-up that needs to be done whether the promise was rejected or resolved. See the [full
>      specification](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback) for
>      more information.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XMk7/)

Comment: You should mention it is in versions 1.1.5 and later.

Comment: @Duncan Right, I've said it's rather new and added a link to the commit message, but I guess saying the version number is also a good idea - this is what I get for living on the repo :)

Comment: @Reno Please check which version of Angular you're using and the fiddle I added to the answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum my bad I was using 1.0.7, it works like a charm indeed :)

Comment: Tried the always callback, but for some reason the code inside is fired before the request is actually completed. So had to stick with `promise.then` :(

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the current angular v1.2.15. Looks like always doesn't exist anymore, I'm getting an error. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Note: The [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) includes the following proviso, "Because finally is a reserved word in JavaScript and reserved keywords are not supported as property names by ES3, you'll need to invoke the method like promise['finally'](callback) to make your code IE8 and Android 2.x compatible."

Comment: I've plagiarized your answer on another question ([Angular equivalent of .done in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18755085/575530)). I hope that's OK.

Comment: @dumbledad it's not plagiarism since you provided attribution - plagiarism is when you claim the content as your own. It is explicitly allowed to quote and use other answers with attribution in SO - that's the content license (scroll to the very bottom of every page - it's always there). So to sum it up - yes, what you did is perfectly fine and you don't have to ask for permission or notify me in the future.