# Angular equivalent of .done in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, coffeescript

I cannot find an alternative solution to what I am trying to do, lets say I have this code in jquery:

```
$.get 'file.json', (re) ->
   for k, v in re
      tpl = "<div>{{v.content}}</div>";
      $ '#container'.append tpl
 .done () ->
     impress().init()
```

That works fine because, `.done` executes the code only after the ajax, but angular seems like don't have some like `.done`, and `impress().init()` cannot reinitialize when the content was loaded, therefore there will be a mistake on data binding..

Here is my attempt on angular

```
App.controller 'SomeCtrl', ($scope, $http) ->
   $http.get('file.json')
   .success (res) ->
      $scope.slides = res
   #what could possibly be in here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call `then` after `success`:

```
$http.get('file.json')
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('success again');
  });
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnNLmWD4Cj4vKD8iE93K?p=preview).

Comment: But what if the result is `error` and not `success`? jQuery's `done` is useful because it will run after either case. Does Angular.js include something similar?

Comment: @dumbledad From Angular 1.2 on you can use `finally` to catch either a success or an error.

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs has methods for `success` and `error`. Read the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Comment: jQuery also has both of them. `done` is useful because it gives a place to put code that will run after either success or error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18144212/575530), in one of the answers [Benjamin Gruenbaum suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18144313/575530) using `.always` which is provided on all promises (including the return value from `$http.get`). He includes a useful [code example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XMk7/):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{data}}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var data = {hello:"World!"};
function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('/echo/json/', 'json=' + encodeURIComponent(angular.toJson(data)), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).always(function(data) {
         alert("HI");  
    });
}
```

Benjamin notes that `.always` has been superseded by `.finally`. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/wkt8c8mj/) using `.finally` and the latest Angular.js.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">Hello, {{name}}!</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $http.get('/echo/json/').
    success(function() {
        $scope.name = 'Sidekick';
        }).  
    finally(function() {
         alert($scope.name);  
    });
}]);
```

(N.B. Here's [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), and [nfiniteloop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254225/575530) to [$q 'finally' not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18254205/575530) may also be useful.)