# Angular equivalent of jQuery deferred.always() callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-promise

We can handle response with .always() callback function in jQuery whether response is success or not.

Is there an equivalent of this type of usage in AngularJS?

```
//jQuery
$.get( "test.php" ).always(function() {
  alert( "$.get completed with success or error callback arguments" );
});

//AngularJS
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //success
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    //error
  });

//how can i handle always?
```

Comment: possible (but not exact) duplicate of [angular $http / jquery complete equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18144212/1048572)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`finally` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) of Angular promises.

Answer (score 1):

The [finally()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback) method from [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service used for this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //success
}).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
    //error
}).finally(function() {
    //Callback method
    //Executed always, no matter of success or fail
});
```

An important notice when returning promises from `finally()` callback:

> `finally` returns a promise, which will become resolved with the same
>   fulfillment value or rejection reason as promise. However, if `callback`
>   returns a promise, the resolution of the returned promise will be
>   delayed until the promise returned from callback is finished.